# How to add page break

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports* applied to my web application 
I wanna put new page every time my date filed $F{date} change 
I already tried drag break element with page break option from palette of *iReport* and drop it onto filed ->($F{date})

But nothing happened
 
please give me any advise or solution

Comment: You can use [data grouping](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups), for example. In this case you can start new group with new page (the *isStartNewPage* property).

Comment: Hmm...may be you can try setting the Break's element printWhenExpression = !$F{date}.isEmpty(). Just a suggestion, i haven't tried it.

Comment: i appreciate you guys help, especially to @Alex K. your comment is much more helpful. i tried as you told me. after that  it's work !!! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create two variables (in this order):

```
1. var_date_prev = $V{var_date}
2. var_date = $F{date}
```

Varibles are evaluated in order in which they are declared so var_date_prev will have date value from previous row.

Add property net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row on field after which you want to make page break and set the expression for the property

```
$V{var_date_prev} != null && $V{var_date_prev} != $V{var_date}
```